# Utilisation de « tandis que » ?

Tags: grammaire

Est-il possible d'utiliser « tandis que » avec le même pronom personnel?

Par exemple,

```
J'écoutais la radio tandis que je lisais un livre. 

J'écoutais la radio en lisant un livre.
```

Comment: C'est plus possible que d'écouter la radio tout en lisant un livre. Tu aurais pu choisir des activités plus compatibles comme par exemple: *J'écoutais la radio tandis que je conduisais ma voiture/en conduisant ma voiture*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oui, on peut utiliser « tandis que » avec le même pronom personnel que celui de la proposition principale. Considère ces exemples :

> J'ai fait sa connaissance tandis que j'étais à Paris.

> Tandis que je me promenais dans la chambre après dîner, allant et venant de long en large, je l'entendais qui en faisait autant que moi dans l'antichambre ; quoique la porte fût ouverte, il n'entrait jamais et nous ne nous disions pas un mot ; mais de temps en temps nous nous regardions pleurer. (Musset, 1866)

Certains ont suggérés qu'à sa base, « tandis que » est équivalent à l'expression latine « tam diu » pour vouloir dire « aussi longtemps » (Guimier 2000). Par contre, il peut aussi être utilisé pour faire des contrastes :

> Certains types de cancers sont en régression, tandis que d'autres se développent.

Bien que cet exemple ne s'applique pas au sens le plus strict de ta question, le concept s'applique : lorsqu'il est utilisé pour indiquer un contraste, ce serait rare d'utiliser le même pronom personnel dans les deux propositions puisque ce serait logiquement très rare de se contraster avec soi-même.

En d'autres mots, lorsque cela signifie « quand » ou « lorsque » le même pronom personnel peut être utilisé. Cependant, à mon avis, c'est assez rare puisqu'on préfère utiliser un de ces substituts.

Je recommande fortement la lecture de l'article par Guimier (2000) - il donne beaucoup d'informations sur l'usage et l'étymologie de « tandis que. »

---

#### Sources

- Guimier, C. (2000). Non-congruence et congruence : alors que vs tandis que. Syntaxe et Sémantique, 1, 80-112. https://doi.org/10.3917/ss.001.0080
- Musset, A. d., Musset, P. d. (1866). Confession d'un enfant du siècle. France: Charpentier.